# Keras ML Model to identify speaker not working

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

- I have a movie with a list of characters. I have each sentence spoken within the movie extracted in small audio snippets. These range from 1 to 4 seconds.
- I want all sentences which were spoken by a particular character. Since I cannot and don't want to identify every single character, I modeled a binary problem: Is the given audio file spoken by character X or not?
- I now tried to develop my model to identify exactly that. Here is what I have:
- Using TF and Keras
- I have 2000 audiofiles, each 1s long of the speaker X
- I have 5000 audiofiles, each 1s long of all non_X speakers.
- For feature extraction, I calculate the Log-Mel spectrogram
- I then feed that input into the following model (I tried numerous architectures, but I currently have this one):

```
def residual_block(x, filters, conv_num=3, activation="relu"):
    # Shortcut
    s = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (1, 1), padding="same")(x)
    for i in range(conv_num - 1):
        x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
        x = keras.layers.Activation(activation)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same")(x)
    x = keras.layers.Add()([x, s])
    x = keras.layers.Activation(activation)(x)
    return keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(x)


def build_model(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input")

    x = residual_block(inputs, 16, 2)
    x = residual_block(x, 32, 2)
    # x = residual_block(x, 64, 3)
    # x = residual_block(x, 128, 3)
    # x = residual_block(x, 128, 3)

    # Convert the 2D outputs (height x width x channels) from CNN to sequences for RNN
    x = keras.layers.Reshape((-1, x.shape[-1]))(x)

    # Recurrent layers for analyzing sequences of extracted features (RNN)
    x = keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(x)
    # x = keras.layers.LSTM(128)(x)

    # x = keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=3)(x)
    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu")(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)

    # outputs = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation="softmax", name="output")(x)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output")(x)

    return keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

The problem:
When testing the model on the datasets it was fine-tuned with, it always predicts out the correct speaker (X or not_X). When using different audioclips of the same movie, it basically always predicts X and never not_X. I'm overfitting I guess, but I'm at a point where I'm really lacking the basic knowledge to even identify the problem area. Is it because my Non_X datasets consist of multiple characters and hence confusing my model? Is my architecture too complex, too simple? Something else?

Comment: Just to be clear. Are you testing with the training data?

Comment: Both. I tested with the training data, which looks fine. Then I test with audio clips which arent test datasets, but belong to the same movie. There it fails.